# MySQL: constant "Searching rows for update" on tiny table

Tags: mysql, innodb, amazon-rds

I have the following table in my MySQL schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `security_token` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `customer_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `expiration_date` datetime NOT NULL,
 `token_string` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `user_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `security_token_token_string` (`token_string`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7054 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The following query is often executed (multiple times a minute) and sometimes takes in excess of 3 minutes to execute:

```
UPDATE security_token
SET expiration_date = '2016-09-01 18:20:37'
WHERE user_name = 'john.smith' AND token_string = 'mLBgrOXfVsXewCV333dVdvvDdxghJqQRU' AND customer_id = 3
```

If I perform a `SHOW PROCESSLIST` the status is:

```
| 33515563 | db_user | 192.168.0.7:41058 | application_schema | Query | 116 | Searching rows for update | UPDATE security_token SET expiration_date = '2016-09-02 18:12:28' WHERE user_name = 'john.smith' AND ... |
| 33515576 | db_user | 192.168.0.7:41062 | application_schema | Query | 113 | Searching rows for update | UPDATE security_token SET expiration_date = '2016-09-02 18:12:28' WHERE user_name = 'john.smith' AND ... |
| 33515587 | db_user | 192.168.0.7:41064 | application_schema | Query | 110 | Searching rows for update | UPDATE security_token SET expiration_date = '2016-09-02 18:12:29' WHERE user_name = 'john.smith' AND ... |
| 33515609 | db_user | 192.168.0.7:41067 | application_schema | Query | 106 | Searching rows for update | UPDATE security_token SET expiration_date = '2016-09-02 18:12:30' WHERE user_name = 'john.smith' AND ... |
| 33515631 | db_user | 192.168.0.7:41071 | application_schema | Query | 104 | Searching rows for update | UPDATE security_token SET expiration_date = '2016-09-02 18:12:45' WHERE user_name = 'john.smith' AND ... |
| 33515665 | db_user | 192.168.0.7:41076 | application_schema | Query | 101 | Searching rows for update | UPDATE security_token SET expiration_date = '2016-09-02 18:13:12' WHERE user_name = 'john.smith' AND ... |
| 33515708 | db_user | 192.168.0.7:41081 | application_schema | Query | 98  | Searching rows for update | UPDATE security_token SET expiration_date = '2016-09-02 18:13:28' WHERE user_name = 'john.smith' AND ... |
| 33515710 | db_user | 192.168.0.7:41086 | application_schema | Query | 93  | Searching rows for update | UPDATE security_token SET expiration_date = '2016-09-02 18:13:29' WHERE user_name = 'john.smith' AND ... |
| 33515711 | db_user | 192.168.0.7:41090 | application_schema | Query | 88  | Searching rows for update | UPDATE security_token SET expiration_date = '2016-09-02 18:13:36' WHERE user_name = 'john.smith' AND ... |
| 33515712 | db_user | 192.168.0.7:41092 | application_schema | Query | 85  | Searching rows for update | UPDATE security_token SET expiration_date = '2016-09-02 18:13:58' WHERE user_name = 'john.smith' AND ... |
```

The table has only 6k rows and is 1.2MB in size. The entire schema is 300MB in size and is currently running on an Amazon RDS db.m4.xlarge instance.

I'm not sure why this query is causing so much trouble, can anyone provide any pointers where to look/tune? Unfortunately I cannot enable the performance schema as this is a production database.

**Update with more info**

I am running version `5.6.19-log`, there are no triggers on this (or any) table. This table's primary key is not referenced in any other tables.

I have the following queries listed as blocking:

```
SELECT * FROM INNODB_LOCKS WHERE LOCK_TRX_ID IN (SELECT BLOCKING_TRX_ID FROM INNODB_LOCK_WAITS);
+----------------------+-------------+-----------+-----------+---------------------------------------+--------------------+------------+-----------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| lock_id              | lock_trx_id | lock_mode | lock_type | lock_table                            | lock_index         | lock_space | lock_page | lock_rec | lock_data                                                   |
+----------------------+-------------+-----------+-----------+---------------------------------------+--------------------+------------+-----------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| 535259585:349:43:132 | 535259585   | X         | RECORD    | `application_schema`.`security_token` | security_token_idx |        349 |        43 |      132 | 'john.smith', 'mLBgrOXfVsXewCV333dVdvvDdxghJqQRU', 3, 70661 |
| 535259584:349:43:132 | 535259584   | X         | RECORD    | `application_schema`.`security_token` | security_token_idx |        349 |        43 |      132 | 'john.smith', 'mLBgrOXfVsXewCV333dVdvvDdxghJqQRU', 3, 70661 |
| 535259583:349:43:132 | 535259583   | X         | RECORD    | `application_schema`.`security_token` | security_token_idx |        349 |        43 |      132 | 'john.smith', 'mLBgrOXfVsXewCV333dVdvvDdxghJqQRU', 3, 70661 |
| 535259581:349:43:132 | 535259581   | X         | RECORD    | `application_schema`.`security_token` | security_token_idx |        349 |        43 |      132 | 'john.smith', 'mLBgrOXfVsXewCV333dVdvvDdxghJqQRU', 3, 70661 |
| 535259575:349:43:132 | 535259575   | X         | RECORD    | `application_schema`.`security_token` | security_token_idx |        349 |        43 |      132 | 'john.smith', 'mLBgrOXfVsXewCV333dVdvvDdxghJqQRU', 3, 70661 |
| 535259574:349:43:132 | 535259574   | X         | RECORD    | `application_schema`.`security_token` | security_token_idx |        349 |        43 |      132 | 'john.smith', 'mLBgrOXfVsXewCV333dVdvvDdxghJqQRU', 3, 70661 |
| 535259573:349:43:132 | 535259573   | X         | RECORD    | `application_schema`.`security_token` | security_token_idx |        349 |        43 |      132 | 'john.smith', 'mLBgrOXfVsXewCV333dVdvvDdxghJqQRU', 3, 70661 |
| 535259570:349:43:132 | 535259570   | X         | RECORD    | `application_schema`.`security_token` | security_token_idx |        349 |        43 |      132 | 'john.smith', 'mLBgrOXfVsXewCV333dVdvvDdxghJqQRU', 3, 70661 |
| 535259554:349:43:132 | 535259554   | X         | RECORD    | `application_schema`.`security_token` | security_token_idx |        349 |        43 |      132 | 'john.smith', 'mLBgrOXfVsXewCV333dVdvvDdxghJqQRU', 3, 70661 |
| 535259551:349:43:132 | 535259551   | X         | RECORD    | `application_schema`.`security_token` | security_token_idx |        349 |        43 |      132 | 'john.smith', 'mLBgrOXfVsXewCV333dVdvvDdxghJqQRU', 3, 70661 |
| 535259546:349:43:132 | 535259546   | X         | RECORD    | `application_schema`.`security_token` | security_token_idx |        349 |        43 |      132 | 'john.smith', 'mLBgrOXfVsXewCV333dVdvvDdxghJqQRU', 3, 70661 |
| 535259544:349:43:132 | 535259544   | X         | RECORD    | `application_schema`.`security_token` | security_token_idx |        349 |        43 |      132 | 'john.smith', 'mLBgrOXfVsXewCV333dVdvvDdxghJqQRU', 3, 70661 |
| 535259543:349:43:132 | 535259543   | X         | RECORD    | `application_schema`.`security_token` | security_token_idx |        349 |        43 |      132 | 'john.smith', 'mLBgrOXfVsXewCV333dVdvvDdxghJqQRU', 3, 70661 |
| 535259541:349:43:132 | 535259541   | X         | RECORD    | `application_schema`.`security_token` | security_token_idx |        349 |        43 |      132 | 'john.smith', 'mLBgrOXfVsXewCV333dVdvvDdxghJqQRU', 3, 70661 |
| 535259525:349:43:132 | 535259525   | X         | RECORD    | `application_schema`.`security_token` | security_token_idx |        349 |        43 |      132 | 'john.smith', 'mLBgrOXfVsXewCV333dVdvvDdxghJqQRU', 3, 70661 |
| 535259522:349:43:132 | 535259522   | X         | RECORD    | `application_schema`.`security_token` | security_token_idx |        349 |        43 |      132 | 'john.smith', 'mLBgrOXfVsXewCV333dVdvvDdxghJqQRU', 3, 70661 |
| 535259521:349:43:132 | 535259521   | X         | RECORD    | `application_schema`.`security_token` | security_token_idx |        349 |        43 |      132 | 'john.smith', 'mLBgrOXfVsXewCV333dVdvvDdxghJqQRU', 3, 70661 |
| 535259520:349:43:132 | 535259520   | X         | RECORD    | `application_schema`.`security_token` | security_token_idx |        349 |        43 |      132 | 'john.smith', 'mLBgrOXfVsXewCV333dVdvvDdxghJqQRU', 3, 70661 |
| 535259519:349:43:132 | 535259519   | X         | RECORD    | `application_schema`.`security_token` | security_token_idx |        349 |        43 |      132 | 'john.smith', 'mLBgrOXfVsXewCV333dVdvvDdxghJqQRU', 3, 70661 |
| 535259517:349:43:132 | 535259517   | X         | RECORD    | `application_schema`.`security_token` | security_token_idx |        349 |        43 |      132 | 'john.smith', 'mLBgrOXfVsXewCV333dVdvvDdxghJqQRU', 3, 70661 |
+----------------------+-------------+-----------+-----------+---------------------------------------+--------------------+------------+-----------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: give index on security_token column

Comment: I would suggest to have the following indices `alter table security_token add index security_token_idx(security_token);`  and `alter table security_token add index token_string_idx(token_string)` and `alter table security_token add index customer_id_idx(customer_id)` If you follow the same precedence on where clause then composite index would be better `alter table security_token add index user_token_customer_idx(user_name,token_string,customer_id)`

Comment: I have added the index: `create index security_token_idx on security_token(user_name, token_string, customer_id)` and this hasn't made any difference, I still see these queries building up in `show processlist` with a long (2 min) execution time.

Comment: This is troubling, at least at first glance. `SELECT @@VERSION;` please?  Are there any foreign keys referencing this table's primary key?  Are there any triggers on this table?  The thread states are simplistic at times, so it may or may not be true that "searching rows for update" accurately describes what's *really* happening here.  The information_schema tables named innodb_trx, innodb_locks, and innodb_lock_waits tables may contain useful info.  If they're all empty, that's useful info also.

Comment: @michael-sqlbot I've updated the initial question with more information, thank you

Comment: I'm fairly sure we've found your problem.   Using the information_schema tables and the processlist, you should find a connection that has a transaction that holds this lock and is sleeping.  Your code isn't properly committing or rolling back a transaction, and everybody else just has to wait.  Until that sleeping connection disconnects, or starts a new transaction (implicitly committing the existing transaction), or is killed this is exactly the behavior you'd expect.  See if you can identify such a situation on your server.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same problem..

If you flush tables/locks/threads by mysqladmin, it should resolve it: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqladmin.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page change